# Sort database records by cost but as if the cost was incremented by 1p per day?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a little maths into sorting a database with MySQL and PHP.

In short, a friend is wanting a website that people pay what they want for the service, but his attention will go to the higher payments, and work down to the lower ones when he has time. 
The easy way would be to order the records by the amount paid, however that would mean a payment of 5p would get priority over something that's been sitting there for 20 days, so I had the idea of incrementing the amount paid by 1p per day.

Is there a way to do this with an sql statement that doesn't involve writing to the table, or should I get everything into a PHP array and do all the calculations there? Alternatively would it be worth having an extra two tables in the database, one with the incremented cost, and the other to keep track of when it was last updated, to avoid having to recalculate it more than once a day?

I'd like to try have the most efficient solution, and while the PHP calculation route seems easiest, I'd have to process all the records at once and then sort them, which might be quite heavy on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this just by using `datediff()`:

```
order by payment + datediff(curdate(), submitdate) desc
```

Comment: Ah thanks a lot, didn't realise it'd be that simple :)